# Java Writing out data to an outside file

Tags: java, file-io

I found a way to write out the data, except, of all the words that should have been written out to the file only the last word appears in the output file.
Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {             
    for (String s: args) {
       //here it gets the file from the doc name in the command line, goes through it, and adds all
       //the words to a vector
       incorporteVocab();
    }
}
public static void incorporteVocab() {  
    String filename = "C:\\projectTests\\vocabulary.txt";  //file where to write out the vocabulary
    for (String w : commonDocumentWords) {  
        if (!inStopList(w)) 
            addToVocabulary(w, filename);
    }
} 
public static void addToVocabulary(String word, String filename) {
        Vocabulary.add(word);       
        toDataFile(word, filename);
    }

public static void toDataFile(String word, String filename) {
    try {
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(filename);
        myWriter.write(word);
        myWriter.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please help,
Thank you!

Comment: Because for each word you open the file all over again which makes you overwrite what was there before. Either open the file once, write all the data, then close it or open the writer in append mode each time you open it.

Comment: got it!! thank you so much!!

Comment: Pass the File rather than the filename.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the second parameter of FileWriter to **true** to make it append the new data to file:

```
FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
```